# Make div scrollable for both axis

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a fixed with and height container with content inside it which expands. How can I make the container scrollable for both axis? I can set overflow-x/y hidden for the container, but it works for only one axis. Here is the code.

```css
.timetable-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: calc(100vh - 120px - 30px);
  background: red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.timetable-container .timetable-inner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.timetable-container .timetable-inner-container .timetable-day {
  width: 350px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="timetable-container">
  <div class="timetable-inner-container">
      <div class="timetable-day">
        <h1 class="day">tuesday</h1>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timetable-day">
        <h1 class="day">wednesday</h1>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timetable-day">
        <h1 class="day">thursday</h1>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timetable-day">
        <h1 class="day">wednesday</h1>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timetable-day">
        <h1 class="day">thursday</h1>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
        <div class="timetable-lesson"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot have a combination of hidden on one side and auto or scroll on the other side.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. It works with overflow set to scroll.

Comment: You did set `overflow-y: hidden;` If you just set overflow to `scroll` or `auto`, it should give you scrollbar on both axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set overflow to scroll it will work for both axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code like my sample, it works for both axis.

```css
.timetable-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: calc(100vh - 120px - 30px);
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```